# How to iterate LEFT JOIN array data in Joomla?

Tags: php, arrays, joomla, mysqli

I'm trying to display an iteration of array values inside PHP. I was able to get it to work with a foreach loop using one table but after joining another table it won't output correctly and I'm lost. The query returns correct results, but I'm not sure how to place it into PHP properly whether using a foreach loop or something else. (in MySQLi)

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
 ->select(array('t.id','t.name','t.abbr','g.date'))
 ->from('#__teams AS t')
 ->join('LEFT', '#__games AS g ON (t.id = g.team2)')
 ->where('t.div LIKE "fbs"')
 ->order('t.id ASC');
$db->setQuery($query);
$teams_class = $db->loadAssocList();
```

With one table I used the following to achieve desired result.

```
$teams = array();
foreach($teams_class as $tc){
    $teams[] = $team = new team();
    $team->id = $tc['id'];
    $team->name = $tc['name'];
    $team->team = $tc['abbr'];
    $teams[$team->team] = $team;
}
```

Now when trying to join a table and add the field date from a second table (#__games) to $teams array I'm not sure what to do. I need it to output like the above except with another variable called $team->date set to equal date. The query prints correctly.

`var_dump($teams_class)` displays:

```
array(125) { 
    [0]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(14) "Boston     College" ["abbr"]=> string(2) "BC" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [1]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(7) "Clemson" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "CLEM" ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-08-31 19:00:00" } 
    [2]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["name"]=> string(13) "Florida State" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "FSU" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [3]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" ["name"]=> string(8) "Maryland" ["abbr"]=> string(2) "MD" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [4]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "5" ["name"]=> string(20) "North Carolina State" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "NCST" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [5]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "6" ["name"]=> string(8) "Syracuse" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "SYR" ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-08-31 14:30:00" } 
    [6]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "7" ["name"]=> string(11) "Wake Forest" ["abbr"]=> string(2) "WF" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [7]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "8" ["name"]=> string(4) "Duke" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "DUKE" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [8]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "9" ["name"]=> string(12) "Georgia Tech" ["abbr"]=> string(2) "GT" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [9]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "10" ["name"]=> string(8) "Miami-FL" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "MIA" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [10]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "11" ["name"]=> string(14) "North Carolina" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "UNC" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [11]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "12" ["name"]=> string(10) "Pittsburgh" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "PITT" ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-09-02 19:00:00" } 
    [12]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "13" ["name"]=> string(8) "Virginia" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "UVA" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [13]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "14" ["name"]=> string(13) "Virginia Tech" ["abbr"]=> string(2) "VT" ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-08-31 16:30:00" } 
    [14]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "15" ["name"]=> string(6) "Baylor" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "BAY" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [15]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "16" ["name"]=> string(10) "Iowa State" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "ISU" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [16]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "17" ["name"]=> string(6) "Kansas" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "KAN" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [17]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "18" ["name"]=> string(12) "Kansas State" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "KSU" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [18]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "19" ["name"]=> string(8) "Oklahoma" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "OKLA" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [19]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "20" ["name"]=> string(14) "Oklahoma State" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "OKST" ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-08-31 14:30:00" } 
    [20]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "21" ["name"]=> string(3) "TCU" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "TCU" ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-08-31 20:00:00" } 
    [21]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "22" ["name"]=> string(5) "Texas" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "TEX" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [22]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "23" ["name"]=> string(10) "Texas Tech" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "TTU" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [23]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "24" ["name"]=> string(13) "West Virginia" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "WVU" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [24]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "25" ["name"]=> string(10) "Cincinnati" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "CIN" ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-08-31 11:00:00" } 
    [25]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "26" ["name"]=> string(11) "Connecticut" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "CONN" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [26]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "27" ["name"]=> string(7) "Houston" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "HOU" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [27]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "28" ["name"]=> string(10) "Louisville" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "LOU" ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-09-01 14:30:00" } 
    [28]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "29" ["name"]=> string(7) "Memphis" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "MEM" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [29]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "30" ["name"]=> string(7) "Rutgers" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "RUT" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [30]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "31" ["name"]=> string(13) "South Florida" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "USF" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [31]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "32" ["name"]=> string(18) "Southern Methodist" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "SMU" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [32]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "33" ["name"]=> string(6) "Temple" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "TEMP" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [33]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "34" ["name"]=> string(3) "UCF" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "UCF" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [34]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "35" ["name"]=> string(4) "Iowa" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "IOWA" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [35]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "36" ["name"]=> string(8) "Michigan" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "MICH" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [36]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "37" ["name"]=> string(14) "Michigan State" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "MSU" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [37]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "38" ["name"]=> string(9) "Minnesota" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "MINN" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [38]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "39" ["name"]=> string(8) "Nebraska" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "NEB" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [39]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "40" ["name"]=> string(12) "Northwestern" ["abbr"]=> string(2) "NW" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [40]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "41" ["name"]=> string(8) "Illinois" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "ILL" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [41]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "42" ["name"]=> string(7) "Indiana" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "IND" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [42]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "43" ["name"]=> string(10) "Ohio State" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "OHST" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [43]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "44" ["name"]=> string(10) "Penn State" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "PSU" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [44]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "45" ["name"]=> string(6) "Purdue" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "PUR" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [45]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "46" ["name"]=> string(9) "Wisconsin" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "WISC" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [46]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "47" ["name"]=> string(13) "East Carolina" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "ECU" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [47]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "48" ["name"]=> string(16) "Florida Atlantic" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "FAU" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [48]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "49" ["name"]=> string(21) "Florida International" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "FIU" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [49]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "50" ["name"]=> string(8) "Marshall" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "MARS" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [50]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "51" ["name"]=> string(16) "Middle Tennessee" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "MTEN" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [51]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "52" ["name"]=> string(13) "Southern Miss" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "USM" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [52]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "53" ["name"]=> string(3) "UAB" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "UAB" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [53]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "54" ["name"]=> string(14) "Louisiana Tech" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "LATC" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [54]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "55" ["name"]=> string(11) "North Texas" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "NTEX" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [55]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "56" ["name"]=> string(4) "Rice" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "RICE" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [56]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "57" ["name"]=> string(14) "UT-San Antonio" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "UTSA" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [57]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "58" ["name"]=> string(6) "Tulane" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "TUL" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [58]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "59" ["name"]=> string(5) "Tulsa" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "TULS" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [59]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "60" ["name"]=> string(4) "UTEP" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "UTEP" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [60]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "61" ["name"]=> string(4) "Army" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "ARMY" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [61]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "62" ["name"]=> string(13) "Brigham Young" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "BYU" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [62]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "63" ["name"]=> string(5) "Idaho" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "IDAH" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [63]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "64" ["name"]=> string(4) "Navy" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "NAVY" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [64]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "65" ["name"]=> string(16) "New Mexico State" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "NMST" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [65]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "66" ["name"]=> string(10) "Notre Dame" ["abbr"]=> string(2) "ND" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [66]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "67" ["name"]=> string(5) "Akron" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "AKRN" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [67]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "68" ["name"]=> string(13) "Bowling Green" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "BGSU" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [68]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "69" ["name"]=> string(7) "Buffalo" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "BUF" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [69]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "70" ["name"]=> string(10) "Kent State" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "KENT" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [70]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "71" ["name"]=> string(13) "Massachusetts" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "MASS" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [71]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "72" ["name"]=> string(8) "Miami-OH" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "MIAO" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [72]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "73" ["name"]=> string(4) "Ohio" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "OHIO" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [73]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "74" ["name"]=> string(10) "Ball State" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "BALL" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [74]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "75" ["name"]=> string(16) "Central Michigan" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "CMIC" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [75]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "76" ["name"]=> string(16) "Eastern Michigan" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "EMIC" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [76]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "77" ["name"]=> string(17) "Northern Illinois" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "NIU" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [77]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "78" ["name"]=> string(6) "Toledo" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "TOL" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [78]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "79" ["name"]=> string(16) "Western Michigan" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "WMIC" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [79]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "80" ["name"]=> string(9) "Air Force" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "AFA" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [80]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "81" ["name"]=> string(11) "Boise State" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "BSU" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [81]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "82" ["name"]=> string(14) "Colorado State" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "CSU" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [82]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "83" ["name"]=> string(10) "New Mexico" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "NMEX" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [83]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "84" ["name"]=> string(10) "Utah State" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "UTST" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [84]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "85" ["name"]=> string(7) "Wyoming" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "WYO" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [85]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "86" ["name"]=> string(12) "Fresno State" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "FRES" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [86]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "87" ["name"]=> string(6) "Hawaii" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "HAW" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [87]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "88" ["name"]=> string(6) "Nevada" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "NEV" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [88]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "89" ["name"]=> string(15) "San Diego State" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "SDSU" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [89]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "90" ["name"]=> string(14) "San Jose State" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "SJST" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [90]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "91" ["name"]=> string(4) "UNLV" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "UNLV" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [91]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "92" ["name"]=> string(10) "California" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "CAL" ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-08-31 21:30:00" } 
    [92]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "93" ["name"]=> string(6) "Oregon" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "ORE" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [93]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "94" ["name"]=> string(12) "Oregon State" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "ORST" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [94]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "95" ["name"]=> string(8) "Stanford" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "STAN" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [95]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "96" ["name"]=> string(10) "Washington" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "WASH" ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-08-31 21:00:00" } 
    [96]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "97" ["name"]=> string(16) "Washington State" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "WSU" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [97]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "98" ["name"]=> string(7) "Arizona" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "ARIZ" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [98]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "99" ["name"]=> string(13) "Arizona State" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "ASU" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [99]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "100" ["name"]=> string(8) "Colorado" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "COL" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [100]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "101" ["name"]=> string(4) "UCLA" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "UCLA" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [101]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "102" ["name"]=> string(3) "USC" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "USC" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [102]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "103" ["name"]=> string(4) "Utah" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "UTAH" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [103]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "104" ["name"]=> string(7) "Florida" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "FLA" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [104]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "105" ["name"]=> string(7) "Georgia" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "UGA" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [105]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "106" ["name"]=> string(8) "Kentucky" ["abbr"]=> string(2) "UK" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [106]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "107" ["name"]=> string(8) "Missouri" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "MIZZ" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [107]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "108" ["name"]=> string(14) "South Carolina" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "SCAR" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [108]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "109" ["name"]=> string(9) "Tennessee" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "TENN" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [109]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "110" ["name"]=> string(10) "Vanderbilt" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "VAND" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [110]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "111" ["name"]=> string(7) "Alabama" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "ALA" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [111]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "112" ["name"]=> string(8) "Arkansas" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "ARK" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [112]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "113" ["name"]=> string(6) "Auburn" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "AUB" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [113]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "114" ["name"]=> string(3) "LSU" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "LSU" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [114]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "115" ["name"]=> string(17) "Mississippi State" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "MSST" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [115]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "116" ["name"]=> string(8) "Ole Miss" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "MISS" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [116]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "117" ["name"]=> string(9) "Texas A&M" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "TAMU" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [117]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "118" ["name"]=> string(14) "Arkansas State" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "ARST" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [118]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "119" ["name"]=> string(13) "Georgia State" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "GAST" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [119]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "120" ["name"]=> string(19) "Louisiana-Lafayette" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "LALA" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [120]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "121" ["name"]=> string(16) "Louisiana-Monroe" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "LAMO" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [121]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "122" ["name"]=> string(13) "South Alabama" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "SOAL" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [122]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "123" ["name"]=> string(11) "Texas State" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "TXST" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [123]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "124" ["name"]=> string(4) "Troy" ["abbr"]=> string(4) "TROY" ["date"]=> NULL } 
    [124]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "125" ["name"]=> string(16) "Western Kentucky" ["abbr"]=> string(3) "WKU" ["date"]=> NULL } }
```

Comment: please do a `var_dump($teams_class);` for us.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added var_dump($teams_class). You'll see that the date only shows up for about ten teams (team2) because that's all that's in the database which is what I want along with all the other teams info..LEFT JOIN accomplishes this. 

Now, in the $teams array, I just need the variable "$team->date = $tc['date'];" to show up right after "$team->team = $tc['abbr'];". Or whatever other method will accomplish this.

Comment: Nevermind..got it working! I must have overlooked when incorrectly typing the team->date variable the first time I tried it. Adding $team->date = $tc['date']; to the array outputs correct data. Rookie mistake. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You could also try something like:

`$team->date = new JDate($tc['abbr']);`

so that the layout can just format the date for you. I prefer returning the correct objects rather than the layouts messing with that sort of thing (layouts should be incredibly stupid).